# The splash screen doesn't change after a "expo publish" command

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, splash-screen, expo-publish

I have a React Native Project with expo already published on the play store, recently I make a change in a view and with the command "expo publish" I was able to up my changes perfectly, but the customer need change the splash screen of the app, so I change the image name on app.json and after the expo publish nothing change, somebody have a idea about what is the problem.

App.json

```
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/images/splash_two.png",
  "resizeMode": "cover",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "assets/images/*",
  "assets/fonts/*",
  "assets/images/splash_two.png"
],
```